# The parameter value of webmethod is having null value

Tags: .net, soap, service

I have developed a .net webservice from a wsdl. The expected soap input has soap body (taken from browser) as

```
<soap:Body>
    <InsertRequest xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/MainType/">
      <InsertRequest>
        <context xmlns="">
          ...
        </context>
        <request xmlns="">
          ...
        </request>
      </InsertRequest>
    </InsertRequest>
  </soap:Body>
```

My customer is sending a soap request with soap body like the below

```
<soap:Body>
    <InsertRequest xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/MainType/">
      <InsertRequest xmlns="">
        <context>
          ...
        </context>
        <request>
          ...
        </request>
      </InsertRequest>
    </InsertRequest>
  </soap:Body>
```

I wrote a dummy application which makes a HttpWebRequest call to the .net webservice. In that if I pass the soap envelope having soap body as below, it works

```
    <soap:Body>
    <InsertRequest xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/MainType/">
      <InsertRequest>
        <context xmlns="">
          ...
        </context>
        <request xmlns="">
          ...
        </request>
      </InsertRequest>
    </InsertRequest>
  </soap:Body>
```

But my customer has given the soap envelope that they send and its soap body is

```
    <soap:Body>
    <InsertRequest xmlns="http://www.xyz.com/MainType/">
      <InsertRequest xmlns="">
        <context>
          ...
        </context>
        <request>
          ...
        </request>
      </InsertRequest>
    </InsertRequest>
  </soap:Body>
```

When I use this soap body in the dummy application, the parameter value in my webmethod InsertRequest(InsertRequest insertRequest) is NULL.
Can any one let me know why the parameter is getting NULL value incase of the above soap body? Also, why there is difference in the soap body's xmlns='' occurance between both the Soap messages?

Thanks in advance,
Harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null parameter normally indicates that the incoming SOAP cannot be serialised to the type.

When you created the service from WSDL, did you do this by hand or did you use a tool?

Try creating a service stub from the WSDL using this tool:
http://www.thinktecture.com/resourcearchive/tools-and-software/wscf
and see if there are any differences in the data contracts / skeleton classes from your implementation. You could then put the implementation code into the skeleton and try calling it using the provided SOAP XML to test interoperability.